# Does GridView have a OnRowSelect event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I know this might be a dumb question but does GridView have a OnRowSelect like OnRowUpdating, OnRowDeleting in ASP.NET C#?

```
protected void GridView_OnRowSelect(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    loc_id_hf.Value = (((HiddenField)(GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("loc_id_hf"))
}
```

When I put the code above inside the event I get an error on e.RowIndex

Any help will be really appreicated.

Comment: check event list of grid view in vs

Comment: I did, it does show the event above but when I try to find a Control inside the GridView I get an error

Answer (score 1):

This is [**event list**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) of gridview, You may need `SelectedIndexChanged`.

Comment: I have a button inside the GridView, what command should I use for the button to fire the SelectedIndexChanged?

Comment: You will get the button click event in RowCommand of the GridView, the example could help you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Put your button inside an template field, and assign it a normal click event like this,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                EnableModelValidation="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="field 1" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="field2" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSelect" runat="server" onclick="btnSelect_Click" 
                                Text="Select" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Your click event looks like this

```
protected void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)b.NamingContainer;
            ////// once you have the row in which the event occured, you can do every thing with it
            // like
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(gvProducts.DataKeys[r.RowIndex].Value);
            // or you can find control like
            HiddenField hf = (HiddenField)r.FindControl("myHiddenField")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable `autogenerateselectbutton = true`. [See more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanging.aspx)

```
<asp:GridVew id="Gridview1" OnSelectedIndexChanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging"
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" autogenerateselectbutton="True">

</asp:GridVew >
```

Event handlers

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {

       GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];

 }

 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
 {

       GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No But it has SelectedIndexChanged event which can serve the purpose. Here is the list of Events supported by GridView. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf8xwy0t.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have to 1st look at this gridview's events with simple insert, update, delete...Here is the link http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/40129-grid-view-save-edit-update.aspx

Then see this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.buttonfield.commandname.aspx It may surly helps you.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="Select")
    {
      int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);    
      GridViewRow selectedRow = CustomersGridView.Rows[index];
      TableCell contactName = selectedRow.Cells[1];
      string contact = contactName.Text;  
      Message.Text = "You selected " + contact + ".";
    }
  }
```

Gridview Looks Like This

```
<asp:gridview id="CustomersGridView" datasourceid="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        autogeneratecolumns="false" onrowcommand="CustomersGridView_RowCommand"
        runat="server">

        <columns>

          <asp:buttonfield buttontype="Button" 
            commandname="Select" headertext="Select Customer" text="Select"/>

          <asp:boundfield datafield="CompanyName" headertext="Company Name"/>

          <asp:boundfield datafield="ContactName" headertext="Contact Name"/>

        </columns>

</asp:gridview>
```

You can also apply `CommandName="Edit", CommandName="Delete" instead of CommandName="Select"`